# CA2000 Microsoft.Reliability error when running StyleCop with VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, stylecop

With this file write code,

```
try
{
    FileStream aFile = new FileStream(doFilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(aFile);
    sw.WriteLine(templateString, fileNameList, topLevelTestbench);
    sw.Close();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("An IO exception has been thrown! {0}", doFilePath);
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();
    return;
}
```

I have this error message with StyleCop.

```
Error   6   CA2000 : Microsoft.Reliability : 
In method 'DoFile.Generate(string, string, string)', call System.IDisposable.Dispose
on object 'aFile' before all references to it are out of scope.
```

What might be wrong with the code?

### ADDED

I again got error from StyleCop when I use the Format method without culture info. Having this code made it work.

```
using System.Globalization;

try  
{   
    string line = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, templateString, fileNameList, topLevelTestbench);   
    File.AppendAllText(doFilePath, line); 
}  
catch (IOException e)            
{
    Console.WriteLine("An IO exception has been thrown! {0}", doFilePath); 
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString()); 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's warning you that you're creating an instance of `IDisposable` which is only used withoun the function and not properly calling `Dispose` on it.  This is due to your use of the `FileStream` instance.  The proper way to resolve this is to use a `using` block

```
using (FileStream aFile = new FileStream(doFilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)) {
  StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(aFile);
  sw.WriteLine(templateString, fileNameList, topLevelTestbench);
  sw.Close();
}
```

**EDIT**

Note: A much easier way to do this is to use `File.AppendAllText`.

```
try 
{
  var line = String.Format(templateString, fileNameList, topLevelTestbench);
  File.AppendAllText(doFilePath, line);
} 
catch (IOException e)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: With the using code, I got Microsoft.Usage Error with the following error message: "Error 6 CA2202 : Microsoft.Usage : Object 'aFile' can be disposed more than once in method 'DoFile.Generate(string, string, string)'. To avoid generating a System.ObjectDisposedException you should not call Dispose more than one time on an object.: Lines: 160 C:\DoFile.cs 160 ModelsimCommunicator".

Comment: @prosseek sounds like you might be hitting the FxCop rule that confuses the dispose pattern of `FileStream` and `StreamWriter`.  I editted my answer and suggested another approach which avoids this entirely.

Comment: I needed to use `String.Format Method (IFormatProvider, String, Object[])`. Thanks for the help.